# Spark Dataframe groupBy and sort results into a list

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe and I would like to group the elements by a key and have the results as a sorted list

Currently I am using:

`df.groupBy("columnA").agg(collect_list("columnB"))`

How do I make the items in the list sorted ascending order?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort dataframe in Spark without using Spark SQL ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741360/how-to-sort-dataframe-in-spark-without-using-spark-sql)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could try the function `sort_array` available in the [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@sort_array(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) package:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("columnA").agg(sort_array(collect_list("columnB")))
```

Comment: How to sort elements in `collect_list()` according to different column in the same `df`?

Comment: @vdep see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426873/9145106)

Answer (score 20):

Just wanted to add another hint to the answer of [Daniel de Paula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38693464/9145106) regarding `sort_array` solution.

If you want to sort elements according to a different column, you can form a struct of two fields:

- the **sort by** field
- the **result** field

Since structs are sorted field by field, you'll get the order you want, all you need is to get rid of the **sort by** column in each element of the resulting list.
The same approach can be applied with several **sort by** columns when needed.

Here's an **example** that can be run in local `spark-shell` (use `:paste` mode):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import spark.implicits._

case class Employee(name: String, department: String, salary: Double)

val employees = Seq(
  Employee("JSMITH", "A", 20.0),
  Employee("AJOHNSON", "A", 650.0),
  Employee("CBAKER", "A", 650.2),
  Employee("TGREEN", "A", 13.0),
  Employee("CHORTON", "B", 111.0),
  Employee("AIVANOV", "B", 233.0),
  Employee("VSMIRNOV", "B", 11.0)
)

val employeesDF = spark.createDataFrame(employees)

val getNames = udf { salaryNames: Seq[Row] =>
  salaryNames.map { case Row(_: Double, name: String) => name }
}

employeesDF
  .groupBy($"department")
  .agg(collect_list(struct($"salary", $"name")).as("salaryNames"))
  .withColumn("namesSortedBySalary", getNames(sort_array($"salaryNames", asc = false)))
  .show(truncate = false)
```

**The result:**

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|department|salaryNames                                                         |namesSortedBySalary               |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|B         |[[111.0, CHORTON], [233.0, AIVANOV], [11.0, VSMIRNOV]]              |[AIVANOV, CHORTON, VSMIRNOV]      |
|A         |[[20.0, JSMITH], [650.0, AJOHNSON], [650.2, CBAKER], [13.0, TGREEN]]|[CBAKER, AJOHNSON, JSMITH, TGREEN]|
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think you can avoid the UDF.        `expr("transform(array_col, x -> x.name)")`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61651832/4335600) is a similar solution that uses a struct to avoid needing a UDF. Written in pyspark too.